# Simple value to only return some array elements rather than all

Tags: javascript

I've made a simple variable '`indexes`' that successfully identifies the indexes in array '`arr`' that are odd numbers, and the previous value is odd and it doesn't test the first number. However, when defining the indexes variable, it initially returns:

```
[undefined, 1, 2, undefined, undefined]
```

I then have to filter out the undefined values to achieve what I want (`[1,2]`).

Is there a way of doing this in 1 line without the need to filter? I can't think of a way of doing it. Also, is there a way of only returning array values for some elements rather than all like map does? I thought to use the some method, but that just returns a boolean rather an array of just some items.

Thanks for any help here. My code is below:

```
let arr = ["9", "9", "9", "4", "6"];
let indexes = arr.map(function(c,i,a){if (i != 0 && c % 2 != 0 && a[i-1] % 2 != 0) {return i} }); // [undefined, 1, 2, undefined, undefined]
indexes = indexes.filter(item => item !== undefined); // [1,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do *this in 1 line*.

You can use `.reduce` with the accumulator, element and index passed through as arguments. Then use the ternary operator as a replacement for your if statement and then use the spread syntax (`...`) to push/append values to the accumulator array:

```js
let arr = ["9", "9", "9", "4", "6"];

const indexes = arr.reduce((acc, elem, i) => (i != 0 && elem % 2 != 0 && arr[i-1] % 2 != 0) ? [...acc, i] : acc, []);
console.log(indexes);
```

**Note**: one-liners are not always better, code readability is important as it helps with the maintainability of your programs.

Comment: ahh I see now. Didn't realise you could use i with reduce. Thanks

Comment: quick question - why is the ', []' needed?

Comment: @user8758206 it’s the initial values of the accumulator. Without it I think it defaults to zero. However, we need it to be an array, so we create an empty array

Comment: @user8758206 also it is the second argument of the reduce method. Reduce takes a function and then a starting value, the `[]` is the starting value

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `reduce` function, which allows you to iterate over a collection and accumulate any data you want:

```
let arr = ["9", "9", "9", "4", "6", "7"];
let indexes = arr.reduce((acc, el, index) => {
     if (index != 0 && el % 2 != 0 && arr[index-1] % 2 != 0) {
         acc.push(index);
     }
     return acc;
}, []);
```

Actually, `filter` and `map` can easily be implemented using `reduce`, as you can initialise an empty array and according to the callback function, you can either add the element to the final array or manipulate the value of each element.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined` ;)

Comment: (fourth argument of reduce)

Comment: Yes I see, no need for it though

Comment: would be easier to reuse the reduce callback, and more functional

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array reduce function

```js
let arr = ["9", "9", "9", "4", "6"];
let indexes = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr, i, a) {

  if (i !== 0 && curr % 2 !== 0 && a[i - 1] % 2 !== 0) {
    acc.push(i);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(indexes)
```